# Adding a single backslash to a string to use in querying a Lucene Index

Tags: c#, lucene

I am trying to add a single backslash in a string that has spaces.  I am using `String.Format` method.  Here is the code.

```
query = "Field1:Web Services";

var hasSpaces = query.Contains(" ");

if (hasSpaces)
{
   var qfix = '\u005c' + " "       
   var newQueryString = query.Replace(" ", qfix);
}
```

I would expect to see a string like
If `query = "Field1:Web Services";`
then `newQueryString = "Field1:Web\ Services";`
but what I am seeing is `"Field1:Web\\ Services"`

So this will not work for a Lucene query that needs a backslash before a space to query.  Even removing a backslash using 
`var newQueryString2 = newQueryString.Replace("\\", @"\");`  did not work

Just on an aside, I have tried using double quotes around my query parameter but I get the escape backslash when I do this.  So

```
var query2 = string.Format("{0}:\"{1}\"", Field1, Field2);
```

Gives me
`Field1:\"Field2\"`, again, with the backslash in it.

What I am not sure of is why I can do this small fiddle in Linqpad but in a VS .NET 4.5 app I do not get the same results.

I have googled many ways including using a string literal, and using "`\\`" but I always get the second backslash and am unable to remove using query.Replace method.  Why will the above code not work in VS but will work in an app like Linqpad?

Comment: change `var qfix = '\u005c' + " "` to `var qfix = @'\u005c' + " "` Note the `@`.  Understand the backslash is an escape indicator in a string to C#, C and C++. So either use two backslashes  when you want one or in C# use the take-me-as-literal specifier `@` at the start of the string.

Comment: Thanks for the response oh Gread and Powerful, I had tried that too but I get a compilation error.  It chokes on the string literal.

Comment: hmm, sorry. Now that I think about it, my suggestion is completely wrong.

Comment: So the way the code is shown in your post, you're replacing every space with a backslash followed by a space. (u005c is a backslash character). Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Every space needs to be a "\ ".

Comment: then I don't see the problem. What you're showing does seem to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried replacing the spaces with '?' such as below?

```
var parsed = query.Replace(" ", "?");
```

This might help.

Comment: Thanks dacke.geo,  For querying lucene indexes the question mark works and does not have the escape char problems that the double quotes or the back slash have.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:
var qfix = @"\ ";